# How to delete characters from an element array by conditions in python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, split

I have a column of arrays in  my dataset that looks like this:

```
IDs
["MedGen:100,OMIM:1,Orpha:D23", "na", "na"]
["na", "OMIM:2,MedGen:20,Orpha:D33", "MedGen:500", "na", "na"]
["OMIM:22,Orpha:D36,MedGen:34"]
['MedGen:C1510586,Orphanet:ORPHA106;MeSH:D004827,MedGen:C0014544,Orphanet:ORPHA166463',
  'na',
  'na',
  'na',
  'na',
  'MedGen:C1510586,Orphanet:ORPHA106',
  'MedGen:CN517202',
  'MedGen:CN517202',
  'MedGen:CN517202']
```

I only care about the MedGen ID and I want to clean the array so only the MedGen IDs are left.

How can I clean an array to select only a specific part of an element?

For example my ideal output cleaning the example would look like:

```
IDs
["MedGen:100", "na", "na"]
["na","MedGen:20", "MedGen:500", "na", "na"]
["MedGen:34]"
['MedGen:C1510586',
  'na',
  'na',
  'na',
  'na',
  'MedGen:C1510586',
  'MedGen:CN517202',
  'MedGen:CN517202',
  'MedGen:CN517202']
```

I haven't been sure where to start with this, I've been trying to use the `split()` function but I haven't got very far (especially as the MedGen ID can be in any part of the string in an element, so I can't do something that's coding like "take all strings before the first comma" - are there any other functions I should be trying to code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```py
ids = [
    ["MedGen:100,OMIM:1,Orpha:D23", "na", "na"],
    ["na", "OMIM:2,MedGen:20,Orpha:D33", "MedGen:500", "na", "na"],
    ["OMIM:22,Orpha:D36,MedGen:34"]
]

import re

for i in ids:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        result = re.findall(r"MedGen\s*:\s*\d+", i[j])
        if len(result) == 0:
            pass
        else:
            i[j] = result[0]

print(ids)
```

All you have to do is iterate over all the values in the array/s, and use regex findall to check whether it contains "MedGen:\d\d". If yes, then extract it; if no, then keep it as it is.

## Regex

A quick summary of what `r"MedGen\s*:\s*\d+"` means - You're searching for `MedGen`, followed by 0-or-more-spaces `\s*`, followed by a colon, followed by 0-or-more-spaces, followed by one-or-more digits (`\d+`). If something like this is found, the result will contain the match at index 0. Then we can set that element's value to the match itself.

If not found, we keep the element as it is.

Comment: hi @Robo Mop i was wondering can it be done using list comprehension.?

Comment: so far im able to get this using list comprehension.  `['OMIM:2,MedGen:20,Orpha:D33', 'MedGen:500'] `

Comment: Thank you for this, I see it works on the example, but for some reason it's not working on my real data. It runs with no errors but the output is unchanged - is there a way to make sure ids to being updated, like storing it in a new variable name or something? I've added a real example that doesn't change with your code to my example data in my question if helpful to see what I've got exactly

Comment: Oh actually I see a problem might be from my own doing. ```MedGen``` codes actually start with either ```MedGen:C123``` or ```MedGen:CN123``` is there a way to amend the ```\d+``` to accept digit or letters?

Comment: Changing the regex to ```MedGen\s*:\s*[A-Za-z]+\d+``` seems to have done what I needed (no idea if that's good to do though so if you see this please let me know if it's bad for any reason) - thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you use `list.pop()` TO REMOVE AN ELEMENT FROM A LIST BY INDEX
Call list. pop(index) on a list to remove the element in the specified index.
or USE np.delete() TO REMOVE AN ELEMENT FROM A NUMPY ARRAY
Call `np.delete(arr, obj)` to remove the element at index obj from arr.

this answer is from [kite](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-remove-an-element-from-an-array-in-python) check it out if you have any doute